Getting an error when I try to import custom Python to AWS Lambda layer
I would like to use a custom function in AWS Lambda, and I know it can be done with layers. I don't have access to EC2 but have Linux (not AWS and no AWS CLI).
So I created a "python/test_function.py", which contains a simple function
def add_nums(x,y):
    return x + y

Then I zipped it
zip -r test_function.zip python/test_function.py

and uploaded to AWS Layers. I was able to select it in Lambda.
In the Lambda code, it runs without error:
import test_function

But then I get error here:
print(add_nums(4,5))

{
  "errorMessage": "name 'add_nums' is not defined",
  "errorType": "NameError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 56, in lambda_handler\n    print(add_nums(4,5))\n"
  ]
}

How can I fix it?

Typical form: from file_name import function_name

The key thing to recognize here is that you need to tell Python where it's going to find the definition of the add_nums function (otherwise it would have to look everywhere).
One way to do this is:
from test_function import add_nums

add_nums(4, 5)

The other way to do this is explicitly qualify the function name when called:
import test_function

test_function.add_nums(4, 5)

